# Can't comment on a nomination

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, comments

Over on the [elections page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election), I see a link to "add comment" on every nomination except Arda's.

This is in Chrome 13.0.782.112 on Windows 7. Don't know if that's at all relevant, but better more information than not enough. :)

Comment: I can repro. I wonder if it has to do with the fact he withdrew his nomination temporarily. Perhaps the 'undeletion' is the root cause of the inability to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct Grace Note - he withdrew and then put himself back up for election.  I have unlocked the candidate for now but another withdraw will land him back in locked and ineligible territory.

Comment: Oh. So withdraws _are_ supposed to be irreversible?

Comment: @badp - withdraws are reversible but multiple withdraws / re-nominations during the same election is not seen as a very positive start for a candidate running for a moderator position.

Comment: I can't believe this use case was contemplated... you never cease to amaze me